# how to check does element present in xml or not in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

here goes my xml tag

```
<NewDataSet>
     <EETaxAmount>
          <WageID>TX01</WageID>
          <WageDesc>WithHoldingTax</WageDesc>
          <TaxAuthorityName>FED</TaxAuthorityName>
          <TaxAuthorityType>10</TaxAuthorityType>
          <Amount>931.25</Amount>
          <YTDAmount>982.92</YTDAmount>
     </EETaxAmount>
     <EETaxAmount>
          <WageID>TXS1</WageID>
          <WageDesc>WithHoldingTax(S)</WageDesc>
          <TaxAuthorityName>FED</TaxAuthorityName>
          <TaxAuthorityType>10</TaxAuthorityType>
          <Amount>50.00</Amount>
          <YTDAmount>50.00</YTDAmount>
     </EETaxAmount>
</NewDataSet>`
```

now my question is i have to display the value witholdingtax as withholdingtax(R) if i have withholdingtax(s) in dataset else as withholdingtax my xsl is as below

```
<xsl:for-each select="//NewDataSet/EETaxAmount">
  <xsl:sort select="TaxAuthorityType"/>
  <tr>
    <td class="txt5">
      <xsl:value-of select="WageDesc"/>
    </td>
    <td class="txt5">
      <xsl:value-of select="TaxAuthorityName"/>
    </td>
    <td class="txt_currency">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Amount >=0 and Amount &lt;=1">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Amount,'0.00')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Amount, '###,###.00')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
    <td class="txt_currency">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="YTDAmount >=0 and YTDAmount &lt;1">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(YTDAmount,'0.00')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(YTDAmount, '###,###.00')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Punctuation is your friend. If you want people to understand and help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="WageDesc[text() = 'WithHoldingTax(S)']">
withholdingtax(R)
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
withholdingtax 
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: hi thnx for ur advise but it will replace every withholding Tax(s) with with hoding(R) and i got the answer by my own and it goes as follows
<xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="count(//NewDataSet/EETaxAmount[WageDesc ='WithHoldingTax(S)'])>0 and WageDesc='WithHoldingTax'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="WageDesc"/>(R)
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="WageDesc"/>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>

Answer (score 1):

In the template matching `WageDesc` use:

```
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(., substring('(R)',
                       4 - 3*(/*/*/WageDesc = 'WithHoldingTax(S)')
                       )
          )"/>
```

**Do note**: In many cases as in this one, no XSLT conditional instructions (such as `<xsl:choose>` or `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>`) are required.

**Another clean way to avoid tangled logic** is to use two separate templates matching `WageDesc` each for one of the two conditions:

```
 <xsl:template match="WageDesc[/*/*/WageDesc = 'WithHoldingTax(S)']">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '(R)')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="WageDesc">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 for good answer. Note to readers: when the first of the two templates above matches an element, it will be used, even though the second template also matches the same element. This is because the first template has higher default priority (basically because it's "more specific"; see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-default-priority
).

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/*">
  <xsl:if test="WageDesc[text() = 'WithHoldingTax(S)']"><xsl:value-of select="//WageDesc[text() = 'WithHoldingTax(R)']/text()" />  
  </xsl:if>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have doubts concerning where the content node are so i choosed // - maybe you should use more qualified XPath

Mike

Comment: hi mike as per ur advice i have used ur code as follows
`<xsl:if test="//NewDataSet/EETaxAmount/WageDesc[text() = 'WithHoldingTax(S)']">
                          
<xsl:value-of select="//NewDataSet/EETaxAmount/WageDesc[text() = 'WithHoldingTax(R)']/text()" />
                        </xsl:if>`

but it results empty descritpion for every wageDesc
kindly advise

Comment: sorry - forgot the loop - but still qualification - // should be replaced by <NewDataSet> ?

Answer (score 0):

Try as per below

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="count(//NewDataSet/EETaxAmount[WageDesc ='WithHoldingTax(S)'])>0 and WageDesc='WithHoldingTax'">
<xsl:value-of select="WageDesc"/>(R)
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="WageDesc"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```